# vcpkg: library not listed in search results, but present in online repo

Tags: vcpkg

It's simple. I want to use library p-ranav-csv2. I checked that the library is present in the vcpkg repo (https://repology.org/projects/p/?inrepo=vcpkg). But it is not present in vcpkg search (`vcpkg search p-ranav-csv2`).

Is it a different repo my vcpkg is using to search for packages? Or is there another level of complexity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that in case of vcpkg (and unlike to pip or maven), I need to update the vcpkg itself to obtain the new list of packages. So the solution is to:

1. go to the vcpkg directory,
2. `git pull` and,
3. run the bootstrap script (`bootstrap-vcpkg.sh` or `bootstrap-vcpkg.bat`, depending on the platform)